# Echoing an angular scope variable from php

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, if-statement

In php, anything with a `$` in front of it is considered a variable and if I try to echo an angular statement like below

```
if(...) {echo "return $scope.id;";}
```

I get an error saying `$scope` isn't a variable I've defined in php. Does someone know of an easy fix to this?

Comment: learn the difference between client- and server-side programming?

Comment: Paste your code here and yes Franz is right here, answer him too

Answer (score 0):

From [the PHP String documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> The most important feature of double-quoted strings is the fact that variable names will be expanded. See [string parsing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) for details.

You could use a [single-quoted string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) like in the example below (or use [now-doc format](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) though that might be more complex than is necessary).

```
echo 'return $scope.id;';
```

That way it won't interpret $scope as a PHP variable.